# (lldb) Error runtime in xCode

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have two UIViewControllers which first UIViewController shows movie title and then if people click on title in table cell it will navigate to second UIViewController that show about movie's description with long story.

In second UIViewController, I allow my tableview can edit row at index = YES;

When I swipe to left it will show delete button at the right side of cell and then I click Back Button to go back to parent (without closing delete table cell), there will be error (lldb) and the runtime is stopped.

I have tried my times to solve it but it's doesn't help.

Thank for reading.

Comment: lldb is not the error, that's the debugger. What's the actual error that you're getting? (Or are you maybe just hitting a breakpoint?)

Comment: There is no message error. it shows only (lldb) and then runtime has stopped immediately!
if it's breakpoint debugger how I would find it?

I am trying hard now. Please help me. @Sebastian

Comment: in your navigation pane, you have an option to select `breakpoint navigator`. it's the second last icon from right. Check if there are any breakpoints and remove them.

Comment: I have checked already, there is no breakpoints. 
What I have gone so far is looking at Issue Navigator the error is
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6000000c)

and in the debug area is: (lldb)

Comment: @Mab KaaKoo Try adding an `exception breakpoint` and see where the app crashes.